# C# Algorithm Code Not Passing Test Case

Tags: c#, algorithm

The challenge is to calculate the total cost of a meal based on the given input:

1. Meal Cost (without tax or tip) (Given as a double)
2. Tip Percentage (given as an int)
3. Tax Percentage (given as an int)

> **NOTE**: These data types by default must remain this way. I cannot change their initial declaration to be `double` instead of `int`

The given steps are as follows:

1. Read input of the 3 values
2. Compute tip using `tip = mealCost x (tipPercent / 100)`
3. Compute tax using `tax = mealCost x (taxPercent / 100)`
4. Compute the total meal cost by adding `mealCost`, `tip`, and `tax`.
5. Round the final answer and print it out (as "The total meal cost is `totalCost` dollars.")

So my program went along the lines of this:

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System;

class Solution {

    // Complete the solve function below.
    static void solve(double meal_cost, int tip_percent, int tax_percent) {
        double tip = meal_cost * (tip_percent / 100.0);
        double tax = meal_cost * (tax_percent / 100.0);

        double totalCost = (meal_cost + tip + tax);

        Console.WriteLine("The total meal cost is {0} dollars", Convert.ToInt32(totalCost));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        double meal_cost = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        int tip_percent = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int tax_percent = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent);
    }
}
```

However, despite my output being identical (down to before the rounding even occurs) HackerRank still identifies my solution as "failed" on it's test cases but not my custom test cases. Is there any explanation for this?

> **NOTE**: The formula provided by HackerRank is actually (Meal Cost) x Tax Percent / 100. I just wrote down the implementation

Comment: are you sure that the formulas are correct?

Comment: Dunno, but you're converting a double to an int so you'll lose any cents (unless your cost are also in cents)

Comment: I forgot to mention: It says to output it as `Your total meal cost is X dollars`. So it is purposely rounded. And @david, I am quite sure the formulas are correct.

Comment: Wait, in your question, you output `The`. But, in your comment, it is `Your`. Also, the output doesn't indicate that it is purposely rounded.

Comment: Did the challenge specify how to round? [ToInt32(double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz(v=vs.110).aspx) uses round to nearest even, it is not unlikely that you have to round halves up always

Comment: @harold No, unfortunately since the languages to be used are variable, it doesn't specify how to round. I used Math.Round in my most recent attempt and that failed.

Comment: I ran some debug tests on repl.it just to make sure @mjwills. I was able to confirm that doing it like the way it is done computes the same result as given in the examples demo'd by HackerRank. I even took the parantheses out and it still didn't work.

Comment: `Math.Round` also rounds to nearest even by the way, but apparently that wasn't the issue

Comment: You do no error checking.  Consider using TryParse after each Console.ReadLine().  If the conversion fails, WriteLine saying "hey, you, the cost is number" or something more polite, and then retrying the ReadLine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a slight typo. You used `dollars` when you should have used `dollars.`.

Upon making that change to your code, it then passed at https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-operators/problem .

Comment: One of the great skills in programming is spotting differences. Whenever I think two things are the same, I copy and paste them into adjacent lines in Notepad++ and compare them character by character.

Comment: Thank You for the words of wisdom. I shall remember to check for even the smallest inconsistencies

Answer (score -3):

Look at the output. The `totalCost` value is output as `integer`. As the `meal_cost` data type is `double`, which might be bigger than the upper limit of `integer`, you should output the `totalCost` as `double`, not cast to `integer`.

```
Console.WriteLine("The total meal cost is {0} dollars", totalCost);
```

Comment: For the purposes of the challenge, these data types are not changed from default.

Comment: Yes, the `solve` function is prewritten, but all the code within the braces is written by me. The arguments that are passed are also predefined. So is the function call and the input for the function call in the Main method

Comment: It doesn't work. The challenge requires you to round the final answer. Notice how the output should be `15 dollars` instead of `15.00 dollars`.

Comment: guess you should include that in your question so everyone can understand.